# How to open port 2195 in iptables CentOS 6 for activating the APNS

Tags: linux, centos, apple-push-notifications, iptables, centos5

I tried this solution:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 2195 -j ACCEPT
/etc/init.d/iptables stop
/etc/init.d/iptables start
```

but still can't access the port.

If there are more ports that I have to open for APNS let me know.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

How about:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2195 -j ACCEPT
service iptables restart
```

[This](https://serverfault.com/questions/148781/unable-to-connect-to-apns-with-java-apns) may help too.

Comment: Just followed this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

Comment: "iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2195 -j ACCEPT" There is a extra hyphen in dport.

Answer (score 8):

It didn't work for me completely, since my last rule was DROP ALL which basically negated all I added to iptables after.

It might be useful to use the -I switch:

`iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 2195 -j ACCEPT`

The `INPUT 1` - means 1st Input rule instead of appending, to put rule in front of drop all

Comment: This fixed my issue - thanks.  NOTE: the command ends with the ACCEPT - the 1 following that above is commentary about the '1' that follows the 'INPUT'.

Answer (score 7):

See my anwser here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25229943/1472048

For CentOS 7, you should use "firewall-cmd" command like so:

```
firewall-cmd --add-port=2195/tcp --permanent
```

iptables is not recommended if you use the firewalld service.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command, it worked for me:

> $ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --jport 2195 -j ACCEPT
>
> $ sudo /etc/init.d/iptables save

Comment: /etc command should be executed after executing the before command.