# Can't open web application from server URL

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, opentripplanner

I'm currently trying to incorporate an application called OpenTripPlanner to my web site.  The documentation on [how to set it up loccally](http://docs.opentripplanner.org/en/latest/Basic-Usage/) is clear and I got it to work on my computer fairly easily.  However, I'm now trying to let the user of my website access the web application of OpenTripPlanner.  The way to run it locally is to execute a jar file (`java -jar otp.jar` plus a couple of arguments) and then access the web application at `http://localhost:8080`.

Now I would like to do the same on my Nginx server under Ubuntu 16.04.  Namely, I would like to be able to access OTP web application from `http://67.212.***:8080`.  However, I have no clue how I could do that.

I'm sure OpenTripPlanner is running on the server, but I can't get the web application from the above URL.

I thought that the problem was maybe that the server could only output from certain ports, but it's a long shot.

Anyone as any idea on how I could do this?

Comment: Is the port open on your server? If it is an EC2 box, you can do this from the security settings. Otherwise, I think `iptables` will allow you to do this (see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606582/how-to-open-port-2195-in-iptables-centos-6-for-activating-the-apns#13608149))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone lands on this page in the future, I just want to let you know that Will was indeed right, the given port wasn't open on the server.  But instead of just opening it and make it available to the World Wide Web to do anything with it, I instead putted a [reverse proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) in place.

Comment: @Lece Thanks for the heads up! Will do as soon as I have time (most likely tonight)